# Wrong Date Getting Saved For An Attribute

Tags: magento-1, attributes, ce-1.5.1.0

I have created an attribute `release_date` with `Date` as the input type.When the date is selected as "29-04-2013", it gets saved as "29-04-0013".What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

IF you take a look @

Admin -> System -> Configuration -> CATALOG -> Catalog -> Date & Time Custom Options -> Date Fields Order

The 'year' select have a value of 'y'   (y = A two digit representation of a year   Examples: 99 or 03)

Take a look @ /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Date.php seem to display the date